# Replace and like in Joins

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two tables tbl_words with column words and tbl_keywords with column keywords and the sample data in the table is as follows

***`Input:`***

**tbl_words**

```
Word
house for rent in ohio
```

**tbl_keywords**

```
keywords
house
rent
```

Now my objective is to join these two tables and **replace** the matching keywords from tbl_keywords with an **empty string('')** in table tbl_words.

**Desired Output:**

```
tbl_words
Word
for in ohio
```

[Schema creation for the above tables](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7563a/1)

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: the output is incorrect I guess ! it should be 2 records with `for rent in ohio  ,,
house for in ohio 
` ?

Comment: @user2841280 I think the question is asking how to replace multiple words at once when the number of words is not known

Comment: I am not gonna select this tbl_words, wanted to update this table tbl_words data with by removing the keywords from other table so the final output will be  a single record by replacing the keywords in tbl_words table.

Comment: You'll need some kind of loop for this, check @Seph answer. (Nice nick btw)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with a CTE to loop over all your words and replace all the words with blank spaces.

Demo here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7563a/21

```
WITH CTE (org, calc, DATA, level) AS
(
    SELECT word, word, CONVERT(VARCHAR(500), ' ' + word + ' '), 0
    FROM    tbl_words

    UNION ALL

    SELECT CTE.org, CTE.data,
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(500), REPLACE(CTE.data, tbl_keywords.Keyword + ' ', '')), CTE.level + 1
    FROM    CTE
    INNER JOIN tbl_keywords ON CTE.data LIKE '% ' + tbl_keywords.Keyword + ' %'
        COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
)
SELECT DISTINCT org, LTRIM(RTRIM(data)) AS DATA, level
FROM CTE
WHERE level =
    (SELECT MAX(level) FROM CTE c WHERE CTE.org = c.org)
```

The adding of `' '` to the start and end of each word is to allow you to have words like `'acters'` not affect `'characters'` otherwise it would simply become `'char'`. It also prevents having to deal with multiple space characters in the middle of your phrase such as `' for  in ohio'`.

This will need to be adjusted if you have punctuation in your sentance such as `'houses for sale. in ohio'` but that can be left as an exercise for you to finish.

Edit:

depending on your performance this approach might be better (description after)...

```
create function [dbo].[Split] 
( 
    @string nvarchar(MAX), 
    @delimiter nvarchar(10) 
) 
returns @table table 
( 
    [Value] nvarchar(MAX) 
) 
begin 
    declare @nextString nvarchar(MAX) 
    declare @pos int, @nextPos int 
    declare @commaCheck nvarchar(1) 

    set @nextString = '' 
    set @commaCheck = right(@string, 1) 
    set @string = @string + @delimiter 

    set @pos = charindex(@delimiter, @string) 
    set @nextPos = 1 
    while (@pos <> 0) 
    begin 
        set @nextString = substring(@string, 1, @pos - 1) 

        insert into @table 
        ( 
            [Value] 
        ) 
        values 
        ( 
            @nextString 
        ) 

        set @string = substring(@string, @pos + 1, len(@string)) 
        set @nextPos = @pos 
        set @pos = charindex(@delimiter, @string) 
    end 
    return 
end
```

with the query now becoming:

```
SELECT RTRIM(combined) AS [words] FROM
(SELECT word, 
(
select [value] + ' ' as [text()]
from dbo.split(word, ' ')
where [value] not in (SELECT [keyword] from tbl_keywords)
FOR XML PATH('')
)
 as [combined] 
from tbl_words) x;
```

Basically we split the phrase into individual words, remove the ones which are key-words and then concatenate them back together using FOR XML PATH.

On my system this runs 6 times faster, but it will depend how long your phrases are and how many words you have. To further improve performance put a (ideally unique) index on [tbl_keywords].[keyword].

Again this won't work for punctuation so you will need to adjust everything accordingly for that if you need it.

Comment: Hi @seph I have a huge data and it taking more time to loop through can it be done other way around.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT replace(w.word, k.keyword, '') as REPLACED_KEYWORDS
FROM #tbl_words w
JOIN #tbl_keywords k
ON w.word LIKE '%' + k.keyword + '%'
```

**[SEE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7563a/14)**

Comment: No good, if you must replace two token (as the example) you can't apply that (I've deleted my answer for that)